# How many scale points can you have on a Van Westendorp survey?

Tags: survey, matrix, likert

I am conducting a Van Westendorp pricing survey. The market I am looking at has a wide range of prices (£3,000 to £33,000), how many scale points can I use for my Van Westendorp question to accurately reflect this diversity?